# Custom/Dynamic label width using auto layout

Tags: ios, width, uilabel, autolayout, xcode5

I have a table cell on which I presently have a UILabel say labelA whose height is dynamic i.e. based on the content. The label width is 290px. I wish to add another label next to labelA whose name is say labelB. The table cell and labelA looks as per below: [image]

***Question 1*** - Here the height is expanding and I have 2 rows to display the entire text here. But it looks like width for the 1st and 2nd row is same as 290. Is there a way I can stop the width of the label where my text ends i.e. in this case the width of my label for 1st row should be 290 but for 2nd row it should end after the last work "Paul" so that I can start my next label labelB from there?

***Question 2*** - Also, while creating the xib, I am placing both my labels on the same row. If I set a constraint between both the labels, can labelA push labelB down to another row when it expands?

My cell and labels finally should look as below where the label with purple background is labelA and rect with orange border and white solid color inside is labelB.

[image]

Please let me know if this is possible? I am still a noob in iOS and auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

To answer **Question 1**, `UILabel` will always draw text into a rectangular frame. You can't have one UILabel draw two lines of text the way you're looking for. You could use two `UILabel`s, one for each line, but you'd have to do some manual calculations to figure out how much text will fit in the first label, and then what text to "overflow" to the second ([`boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3acontext%3a) would be your friend for this).

To answer **Question 2**, you should pin the bottom edge of *labelB* to the bottom edge of *labelA*. Let the height of each label be determined by the intrinsic content size. Assuming the font is the same, this should result in the result you want. (You can also try aligning the two labels' baselines, but I can't recall how that behaves for multiline labels.)

By the way, you should look into [iOS 7's Text Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html). I personally haven't had a chance to dive into it in much depth yet, but it's very powerful and you might find a better way to do what you're after here.